# Ruby Combinations based on Value

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out a way to use Ruby's [combination](http://chriscontinanza.com/2010/10/29/Array.html) method to return combinations whos sum equals a certain amount.  I may not be familiar enough with Ruby or understand if I can add any lambda expressions essentially to the combinations result, is there a way to do what I want with the combination method or is it very limited?  Like can you add extra criteria around the combinations result based on some criteria?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Add some details and show some (pseudo) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`combination` returns an `Enumerator`, which you can then filter to get only the combinations you want.

Take this example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].combination(2).
   select { |n| n.reduce(:+) == 8 } # => [[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks, what about if you can combine duplicate numbers to == the number?  like 1+1+1+4 :)

Comment: In that case you can use `repeated_combination` instead of `combination`.